# Cant get Android Tutorial to work, beginner programmer

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm fairly new to Android programming and in general my programming skills are lacking. I was following a Head Start tutorial even though I know it had technically been removed to be updated or something. anyways I got up to a part where they just want you to copy and paste a code to get the NASA RSS feed and the android application to communicate with one another, but for some or other reason nothing displays. I just get a white screen and the logcat errors seem to not do much to others apps from what I have seen. the test data I used worked so I think the xml's are fine so maybe it is my Java. I cant seem to find anything though. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong. Been trying all weekend. It could be the copy pasted code, but I don't understand it.

```
    package love.android.nasadailyimage;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;


public class NasaDailyImage extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nasa_daily_image);
        IotdHandler handler = new IotdHandler();
        handler.processFeed();
        resetDisplay(handler.getTitle(), handler.getDate(), handler.getImage(), handler.getDescription());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_nasa_daily_image, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class IotdHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private String url = "http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss";
        private boolean inUrl = false;
        private boolean inTitle = false;
        private boolean inDescription = false;
        private boolean inItem = false;
        private boolean inDate = false;
        private Bitmap image = null;
        private String title = null;
        private StringBuffer description = null;
        private String date = null;


        public void processFeed() {
            try {
                SAXParserFactory factory =
                        SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
                reader.setContentHandler(this);
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
                reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                input.close();
                return bitmap;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                 Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("url")) {
                inUrl = true;
            } else {
                inUrl = false;
            }
            if (localName.startsWith("item")) {
                inItem = true;
            } else if (inItem) {
                if (localName.equals("title")) {
                    inTitle = true;
                } else {
                    inTitle = false;
                }
                if (localName.equals("description")) {
                    inDescription = true;
                } else {
                    inDescription = false;
                }
                if (localName.equals("pubDate")) {
                    inDate = true;
                } else {
                    inDate = false;
                }
            }
        }


        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            String chars = new String(ch).substring(start, start + length);
            if (inUrl && url == null) {
                image = getBitmap(chars);
            }
            if (inTitle && title == null) {
                title = chars;
            }
            if (inDescription) {
                description.append(chars);
            }
            if (inDate && date == null) {
                date = chars;
            }
        }

        public Bitmap getImage() {
            return image;
        }


        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public StringBuffer getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
    }


    private void resetDisplay(String title, String date, Bitmap image, StringBuffer description){
        TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        titleView.setText(title);

        TextView dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageDate);
        dateView.setText(date);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);/////////////////////////////////////////

        TextView descriptionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
        descriptionView.setText(description);
    }

}
```

XML in case it helps

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        tools:context=".NasaDailyImage">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/image_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/image_date" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/galaxy"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/image_description" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I would ask someone here, but in my country 'Namibia' there are very few people who do android programming that I have access to.

my LogCat from my S4 device

```
    04-20 11:07:17.204  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:07:17.204  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:07:17.209  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:07:17.209  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:12:38.244  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:12:38.244  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:12:38.244  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:12:38.249  25660-25660/love.android.nasadailyimage W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
04-20 11:16:06.154  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-20 11:16:06.154  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12208: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12214: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
04-20 11:16:06.229  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
04-20 11:16:06.234  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
04-20 11:16:06.234  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9779: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
04-20 11:16:06.234  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 392: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 414: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-20 11:16:06.244  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
04-20 11:16:06.249  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 355: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-20 11:16:06.249  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-20 11:16:06.249  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
04-20 11:16:06.249  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 357: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
04-20 11:16:06.249  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
04-20 11:16:06.369  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 130K, 6% free 16994K/18052K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
04-20 11:16:06.389  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 28.887MB for 11943952-byte allocation
04-20 11:16:06.404  30742-30751/love.android.nasadailyimage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 4% free 28654K/29720K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
04-20 11:16:06.479  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage I/System.out﹕ main(HTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, log to file is false, DBG is false
04-20 11:16:06.594  30742-30742/love.android.nasadailyimage D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

AndroidManifest as requested

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="love.android.nasadailyimage" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".NasaDailyImage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "love.android.nasadailyimage"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

EDIT: added my LogCat and my AndroidManifest

Comment: just a suggestion . this is a very good resource to start learning about android .    https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

Comment: your manifest has right permissions? can you show them?

Comment: ok I added my logcat and android manifest. Sorry i forgot those.

Comment: and thanks for the link Sojan V Jose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do these Android logcat warnings mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065249/what-do-these-android-logcat-warnings-mean)

Comment: Added clarity as to why this post isnt similar to 'What do these Android logcat warnings mean?'

Comment: Running it in different emulators also dont give a different result.

Comment: Can anyone see the problem? I still cant figure it out

Comment: The logcat warning is a seperate issue, not related to why you have a "white screen".

Answer (score 1):

Found a question on StackOverflow, that followed the same tutorial as you. Maybe this might help you

[Android Head First "NASA daily image App"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897456/android-head-first-nasa-daily-image-app)

As mentioned you should use **AsyncTask**, and process the request when it comes back (onPostExecute). The problem with your code is, that you send an request, and right after you call *resetDisplay*, and the response hasn't come back yet... that's why you see a blank screen.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out when I get a chance. Work is a little hectic at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in your ***build.gradle*** file, check the dependencies, you'll see something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

You can try copy pasting that over your dependencies.

Comment: Sorry had to attend to some work. My current dependencies looks like the following 'dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'}'

Comment: Sorry don't quite understand how to format that nicely I'll add my build.gradle in my question.

Comment: Right so they look exactly the same but I still copied it over to double check and it still seems to show me a blank screen. I can see the title bar however just none of my textview or image elements are showing.